# jQuery/JSTree/ASP.net: How to get Newly Created Node's ID from Server

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, jstree

I currently have a JSTree all set up to do the creation and renaming of a new node:

```
.bind("create_node.jstree", function (NODE, REF_NODE) {
               $.ajax({
                   async: false,
                   cache: false,
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: "ApplicationAJAXHandler.aspx?action=CreateMenuItem&ApplicationID=" + document.getElementById('<%=hdnSelectedAppID.ClientID %>').value + "",
                   data: {
                       "operation": "create_node",
                       "ref": REF_NODE.args[0][0].id,
                       "title": REF_NODE.rslt.obj[0].innerText
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
                   }
               });
           })
           .bind("rename_node.jstree", function (NODE, REF_NODE) {
               $.ajax({
                   async: false,
                   cache: false,
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: "ApplicationAJAXHandler.aspx?action=UpdateMenuItem&ApplicationID=" + document.getElementById('<%=hdnSelectedAppID.ClientID %>').value + "",
                   data: {
                       "id": createdNodeID,
                       "title": REF_NODE.rslt.obj[0].innerText
                   }
               });
           })
```

The problem is that my success doesn't seem to get hit when I return an integer ID on the create node, thus I can't set it to a global variable. What exactly do I need to return in the function to get back the ID from the server? I'm simply returning a new integer right now.

Comment: Just to comment. The console.log was simply there for testing. It never gets hit. Previously, I was setting createdNodeID to whatever was returned, but I was never able to return an integer despite the function in my handler returning an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a single JSTree object, serializing it, and sending it through the pipe as JSON. Worked like a charm.